# Getting to grips with pre-loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloading

I am having a few issues with pre-loading images using JS. I have a fiddle in which I am attempting to create three image objects and load them one by one, however I am only getting one image? Any help appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/gq1oqnxb/1/

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        var images = new Array();

    images[0] = 'http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg';
    images[1] = 'http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg';
    images[2] = 'http://wallfc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Little-Birds.jpg';
    var i = 0;      

    while(i < images.length){

    var image = new Image(50,50);
    image.src = images[i];
    image.onload = function(){

                        $('body').append(image);
                        i++;
                                }
    i++
    }



    });

</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/oyxktch2/)

```
imageLoader(0); //call the function with first image to load `0` as index starts from `0`
function imageLoader(i) { //function to load images one by one and pass the array index
    var image = new Image(50, 50); //create a new image
    image.src = images[i]; //set src of the image from images array
    image.onload = function () { //on image load 
        $('body').append(image); //append to the the body
        if (++i >= images.length) return; //increment i check the length of images is exceeded than return
        imageLoader(i); //more images are present in array then call the function again 
    }
}
```